# How do I get X to start without a monitor attached while using NVIDIA drivers?

Tags: centos, xorg, nvidia

**card :** Geforce GT 730
**OS :** Centos 6.5

I'm trying to demo [HP RGS](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/campaigns/workstations/remote-graphics-software.html) on a CentOS 6.5 machine located in a DC offsite. RGS requires X to be running with NVidia HW acceleration, but I can't get X to start headless with the nvidia modules.
I've tried both using [CustomEDID](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/173.14.12/README/appendix-b.html) in the xorg.conf, running `nvidia-xconfig  --allow-empty-initial-configuration`, running both at the same time, and neither.

nvidia related packages :

```
]# rpm -qa | grep nvidia
nvidia-x11-drv-346.59-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64
kmod-nvidia-346.59-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64
nvidia-detect-346.59-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64
```

kernel modules loaded, noveau blacklisted :

```
]# lsmod | grep -i nvid\|nov
nvidia               8368812  0 
i2c_core               31084  1 nvidia
```

lspci output :

```
lspci | egrep 'VGA|3D'
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. G200eR2
08:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1287 (rev a1)
```

here is the current xorg.conf

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath      "/usr/lib64/xorg/modules/extensions/nvidia"
    ModulePath      "/usr/lib64/xorg/modules"
EndSection

Section "Module"

# HP Remote Graphics Extension
    Load           "rge"
# extmod recommended for preventing XID overflow.
    Load           "extmod"
# Ensure X.org defaults are loaded
    Load           "glx"
    Load           "dbe"
    Load           "record"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from data in "/etc/sysconfig/keyboard"
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
    Option         "XkbLayout" "us"
    Option         "XkbModel" "pc105"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # 1920x1080p @ 60Hz (EIA/CEA-861B)
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       26.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     24.0 - 75.0
    ModeLine       "1920x1080_24" 74.250 1920 2558 2602 2750 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "1920x1080_23.976" 74.175 1920 2558 2602 2750 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
    Option         "DPMS"
    Option         "DPI" "96 x 96"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 730"
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Option "ModeDebug" "True"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "CustomEDID" "DFP-0:/etc/X11/edid.bin"
    Option         "UseDisplayDevice" "DFP-0"
    Option         "ConnectedMonitor" "DFP-0"
    # Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT-0"
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    Option         "NoLogo" "1"
    Option         "RenderAccel" "1"
    Option         "TripleBuffer" "1"
    Option         "Coolbits" "1"
    Option         "DamageEvents" "1"
    Option         "RegistryDwords" "PerfLevelSrc=0x3333"
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes      "1920x1080"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Extensions"

# Begin HP Remote Graphics Software
    Option         "Composite" "Disable"
# End HP Remote Graphics Software
EndSection
```

Here is the Xorg.0.log output when trying to start with that configuration :

xauth:  creating new authority file /root/.serverauth.44277

```
X.Org X Server 1.15.0
Release Date: 2013-12-27
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: c6b8 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64
Current Operating System: Linux ws-00.cluster.opengeophysical.com 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6_lustre.gffd1fc2.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jan 12 10:02:20 PST 2015 x86_64
Kernel command line: ro root=UUID=041f043a-ee06-4f90-8197-2d8cbdd1496b rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_LVM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=135M@0M  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet nouveau.modeset=0 rdblacklist=nouveau audit=1
Build Date: 11 December 2014  07:44:11PM
Build ID: xorg-x11-server 1.15.0-25.el6.centos
Current version of pixman: 0.32.4
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.centos.org/Documentation
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Jun 23 11:26:55 2015
(==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
Initializing built-in extension XTEST
Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
Initializing built-in extension SYNC
Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
Initializing built-in extension RENDER
Initializing built-in extension RANDR
Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
Initializing built-in extension RECORD
Initializing built-in extension DPMS
Initializing built-in extension Present
Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
Initializing built-in extension XVideo
Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
Initializing built-in extension SELinux
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
Initializing built-in extension DRI2
Loading extension RGE
Loading extension GLX
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE)
(EE)
Please consult the CentOS support
         at http://wiki.centos.org/Documentation
 for help.
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE)
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
giving up.
xinit:  Connection refused (errno 111):  unable to connect to X server
xinit:  No such process (errno 3):  Server error.
```

Answer (score 4):

Try adding this option to your Section "Device" for the Driver "nvidia".

`Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "true"`

Comment: This option is only available on the newest driver line, not the legacy drivers for older cards.

Comment: Starting with version [460.32.03](https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/168347/en-us) this is the default – _Default `AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration` to True such that the NVIDIA X driver succeeds when launching the X server even if there are no display devices connected._

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure all those options you specify should be in the Device section with the nvidia driver and not the Screen section.

Also UseDisplayDevice can also be set to "none" according to the docs but I have never tried this.

Comment: The appendix I linked earlier says that they can be in the Screen or Device sections. Nonetheless I tried moving the options all to that section and got the same result.

Comment: @echdee Really? I can't find `AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration` option anywhere in [Appendix B. X Config Options](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/173.14.12/README/appendix-b.html).

Comment: *Also UseDisplayDevice can also be set to "none" according to the docs but I have never tried this.* According to [Appendix B. X Config Options](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/173.14.12/README/appendix-b.html) This functionality is **only available on Quadro and Tesla GPUs.**

Comment: _AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration_ is not available in the legacy drivers for old cards and _UseDisplayDevice_set to **None** does not work on _GRID_ GPUs like the Tesla P100

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost I can confirm setting UseDisplayDevice to "none" works on Titan RTX, driver 418.56. In fact, they changed the description in recent documentations (e.g., [the Appendix B I looked at](http://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/418.56/README/xconfigoptions.html))